# If $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure, then $\int f \leq \liminf \int f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Folland's, Real Analysis and I am stuck at the following exercise (2.33).

> If $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure, then $\int f \leq \liminf \int f_n$

It smells like Fatou's, however I couldn't see anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By the definition of $\liminf$, there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ of $f_n$ such that:
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int f_{n_k} = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n
$$

$f_{n_k}$ also converges in measure to $f$. To see why, notice that the sequence $\mu\left(\left\{ x: \left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right|\geq \epsilon \right\}\right)$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, its subsequence $\mu\left(\left\{ x: \left| f_{n_k}(x) - f(x) \right|\geq \epsilon \right\}\right)$ also converges to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. This is a basic result in sequence convergence.

By theorem 2.30 in Folland's book, there is a subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ that converges pointwise a.e. to $f$. Call it $f_{n_{k_j}}$. Notice that it also satisfies:
$$
\lim_{j \to \infty} \int f_{n_{k_j}} = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n
$$

Apply Fatou's lemma to $\{f_{n_{k_j}}\}$, and put it all together to find that:
$$
\int f = \int \lim_{j \to \infty} f_{n_{k_j}} \le \lim_{j \to \infty} \int f_{n_{k_j}} = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n
$$

Comment: Thanks for helps. But I have one question. How can we verify that if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then $\exists$ a convergent subsequence (if not itself) $f_{n_k} \to f$ also? Is there a specific theorem for this (or is it obvious)?

Comment: In particular, rigorously, we define the convergence in measure, $$\mu\left( \left\lbrace x: \left\lvert f_n(x) - f(x) \right\rvert \geq \epsilon \right\rbrace \right) \to 0$$as $n \to \infty$. Then, how can we say this for $f_{n_k}$ and we say this for as $n \to \infty$ or $k \to \infty$ or both?

Comment: @John This is theorem 2.30 in Folland's book. Convergence in measure implies the existence of a subsequence that converges pointwise a.e..

Comment: OK thanks, then I guess right after the equation you have a typo? You wrote: "Since $f_{n_k}$ also converges in measure to $f$...". I ask do we know this subsequence also converges in measure? Thm. 2.30 says the subsequence converges a.e. to $f$, not in measure as far as I remember.

Comment: @John No, it's not a typo. I've expanded my answer to explain what results I use and where. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: OK now it is clear to me. Thank you for help!

Comment: @John Happy to help!

Comment: @Ayman Which definition of lim inf are you using? How do we know the lim inf is a subsequential limit?

Comment: @Ray The definitions are equivalent and guarantee the existence of such subsequence. Check out the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior). Which definition do you have in mind?

Comment: @Ayman I'm wondering why you can say that the $\liminf$ is equal to some subsequential limit. From the definition the $\liminf$ is the infimum of the set of subsequential limits. How do we know it is actually attained i.e. is a member of the set of subsequential limits? I think we only know there is a subsequence $\int(f_{n_k})$ such that $\lim \int f_{n_k}$ is greater than or equal to $\liminf \int f_n$

Comment: @Ray It is slightly well known that both the limit inferior and limit superior are in fact subsequential limits. You can prove this with little machinery. If you want, you can ask a question by clicking on the `ASK QUESTION` button to get things cleared up and get some rep.

Comment: @AymanHourieh So in this problem we're assuming the measure is complete right? Because otherwise, we can't guarantee that $f$ would be integrable. I think you're implicitly using the fact that if $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $f_n$ is measurable, then $f$ is measurable, which is Prop 2.11 b, and this is true iff the measure is complete.