# For $f_n$ non-negative, if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then $\int f \leq \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This question is answered in [If $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure, then $\int f \leq \liminf \int f_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276138/if-f-n-geq-0-and-f-n-to-f-in-measure-then-int-f-leq-liminf-int-f-n).

I still have one question, why do we need to obtain a subsubsequence (denoted as $f_{n_{k_j}}$ in the linked question)? Why is working with the subsequence $f_{n_k}$ not enough?

I know this would be better as a comment on the previous question, but it is old so I doubt I will get a response at all.

Comment: take also a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944695/if-f-j-to-f-in-measure-show-that-int-x-f-d-mu-le-varliminf-int-x-f-j-d) if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Convergence in measure does not imply almost sure convergence. Since Fatou's Lemma requires almost sure convergence it is necessary to use the existence of  a subsequence which converges almost surely.